# What is the value of $BC^2$ in the following diagram?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB=20$ and $AC=22$. Suppose its incircle
> touches $BC,CA$ and $AB$ at $D, E$ and $F$ respectively, and $P$ is
> the foot of the perpendicular from $D$ to $EF$. If $\angle BPC=90$
> degrees, then compute $BC^2$.

I couldn't figure out where to start. Can I get a hint?

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, the guy is struck and asking for hints to start and you are asking him to show attempts?

Comment: @JeanMarie, thank you and a good morning from locked India

Comment: @Jacob Frye OK. The last hint. Prove that $\Delta ABC$ is a right-angled triangle. Show us  your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: Even when you don't know where to start, you should include more in your question than just a problem statement. You can say whether this is a textbook exercise and, if so, what topic was covered in the chapter. You can say whether trig, coordinates, and/or vectors are fair game, or whether a "synthetic" solution is preferred; you can also say something about the theorems you think might apply (Law of Cosines?, Ceva?, Power of a Point?). Etc. This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time explaining things you know or using techniques beyond your level.

Comment: Are you a high-school student, Jacob? If so, you can afford yourself to think about the problem even for a few days. Maybe this is a perfect time and place to say how students here are lucky. Until I entered uni a few months ago, just like many students in the Eastern Europe, I had more than 15 subjects (not counting music schools and so on). My point is, we all fought and we still are fighting to solve our problems. Our mother-tongue is totally different than English so, many of my colleagues don't understand half of the MSE content. Not to mention our education system...

Comment: Where we're left to do everything on our own.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I appreciate your positive thinking. We all have to cope with different shortcomings wherever we are, not the same ones depending where we were born. Where are you from, Katya ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I'm from Croatia. Katya Verkhovsteva is just a fictional character from the book _Brothers Karamzov_. My real name is Laura. 

Answer (score 1):

Hint (and more):

> Let us consider an *arbitrary* triangle $\Delta ABC$, let $I$ be its incenter, $D,E,F$ the projections of $I$ on the sides, $A',B',C'$ the mid points of the sides of $\Delta DEF$, $P$ such that $DP$ is the height from $D$ in $\Delta DEF$, and draw the Euler circle $PA'B'C'$ for it.
>
> Let  $R,S$ be the intersection of the angle bisector $AA'I$ with the lines $DE$, and respectively $DF$. **Then** $EA'PF\|BR\|CS$.
>
> Let $Q,T,U$ be the intersections of $DP$ with $BR$, $CS$, and respectively $AB$.
>   Denote by a star the reflection w.r.t. the line $DP$. So $Q=Q^*$, $T=T^*$, $U=U$, and also consider the reflected points $F^*$, $B^*$, $C^*$. **Then** $B^*$ is on $PC$, and $C^*$ is on $PB$.
>
> **Then finally:** $PD$ is the angle bisector of $\widehat{BPC}$.
>
> [image: A bisection property of the heights of the pedal triangle of the incenter, dan_fulea]